# getting a response that my Query was empty

Tags: php, mysql

im getting an empty query as the result when i run my update command below on my update page,this is the update command which i have on my script,i have edited and provided the full code

```
     <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "tert") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ub", $connect) or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['status']))
{

    $sql = "UPDATE admin SET Status = '".$_POST['status']."'
    WHERE Status = '".$_POST['status']."'
     ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}




?>
<table width = "70%" cellpadding = "5" cellspace = "5" >
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <table class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>


            <tr>

<td><strong> Last Name </td>
<td><strong> First Name </td>
<td><strong> Staff Id </td>
<td><strong> Status</td>


</tr>

<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr> 

<td> <?php echo $row['lName']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['fName']; ?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['staffId']; ?> </td>
<td><div contenteditable> <?php echo $row['Status']; ?> </td>


</tr>


<?php 

}

?>
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.` What did you expect? And your query does nothing at all, you  are setting a field to the same value again with: `SET Status = '$row[Status]'   WHERE Status = '$row[Status]'`

Comment: Thats your problem: If you UPDATE a field with the same value, NOTHING is updated at all.

Comment: I thing your second `$row[Status]` should be `$_POST['status']` :) But check: SQLInjections in PHP

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I think he doesn't show enough code for us to understand his problem clearly

Comment: @Programming Newb Yep you are right.

Comment: Are you setting status in another page?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your query this way:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE admin SET Status = '".$row['Status']."' WHERE Status = '".$row['Status']."'";
```

Comment: But this will work too: `'$row[Status]' `, ugly, but it works!

Comment: A lot of things work, but it's better if we stick to the conventions, haha. That makes our code less error prone.

Comment: Conventions! hihi, then use MSQLI and prepared statements ;)   `<?=\`whoami\`?>` :))

Comment: I drop this one here: If you UPDATE a field with the same value, NOTHING is updated at all.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator im getting another error  ...Notice: Undefined variable: query line 178 which is  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>

Comment: Remove this previous line: $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); ...There's no need to fetch twice...And the while should be while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($sql) )

Answer (score 0):

What is `$row[Status]` ? Do you mean `$row['Status']` ?

And please go for PDO

Comment: Its ugly but if in PHP the constant `Status` is not defined, it will be used as string. So both are ok and do the same. Only the first throws a notice.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the reason you aren't getting a query is that you defined your $sql inside your if() condition, once that loop is exited, the $sql query becomes empty, so i think you should put $query inside your if condition for you to get back a resultset. your If loop like this

```
if(isset($_POST['status']))
{

    $sql = "UPDATE admin SET Status = '".$row['Status']."'
    WHERE Status = '".$row['Status']."'
     ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Sry there is no **isset loop** you got it completly wrong. `if()` is a condition check, not an iterator like `while()` or `foreach()`  and the $sql variable will be filled and not empty after the if() condition

Comment: I really cant do much if he doesn't provide more code to show clearly the error he has :(

Comment: So lets leave it here :)

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb im getting an error...Notice: Undefined variable: query and a Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in ....on this ... while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>